# How to manipulate limited objects from an array of object using typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of object, I want to manipulate only 2 out of 3 object, When I am using slice, its gives some error(cannot read the property slice of undefined..) in my project, Here working fine. So I want to filter from typescript only and populate in ngfor. Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let data of json.slice(0,02); let i=index">{{data.text}}</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  json: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.json = [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'one'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'two'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'three'
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular, Always use **Angular Pipes**.

[Codesandbox Example Here...](https://codesandbox.io/embed/fragrant-tdd-vwwpt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
<div *ngFor="let data of json | slice:0:2; let i=index">{{data.text}}</div>
```

Comment: I tried already , getting error , object is type unknown

Comment: Can you attach any screenshot of the error?